# how do i add an arbitrary number of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add lists together like a function i found on here but the problem is that i cant figure out how to add more than a specific number of lists. I want it to add an arbitrary number of lists so m+n+o should be [12,15,18] Thanks!

```
m = [1, 2, 3]
n = [4, 5, 6]
o = [7, 8, 9]

def zipper(a,b):
    x = [a[i] + b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
    print x

print zipper(m,n)
```

Comment: have a list of lists and pass that in. `m = [1, 2, 3];
n = [4, 5, 6];
o = [7, 8, 9]; a = [m,n,o];`

then call zipper(a)

Comment: You may accept my answer if you like it ;P

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip`:

```
In [1]: m = [1, 2, 3]
   ...: n = [4, 5, 6]
   ...: o = [7, 8, 9]
   ...: 

In [2]: map(sum, zip(m,n,o))
Out[2]: [12, 15, 18]
```

or `numpy.sum`:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np
In [5]: np.sum([m,n,o],axis=0)
Out[5]: array([12, 15, 18])
```